# Why do I have to use ':host /deep/ .className' to select an element that is dynamically created by angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to better understand why, in order to target an element that is dynamically created by angular and modify its' css properties, I have to use `':host /deep/ .className'` to select that element, instead of just doing `'.className'`.

The component's name is `'app-merchandise-dialog'` and it has this general DOM structure:

```
<app-merchandise-dialog>
 <form>
  <mat-horizantal-stepper>
   <div class="mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container"></div>
   <div class="mat-horizontal-content-container"></div>
  </mat-horizantal-stepper>
 </form>
</app-merchandise-dialog>
```

This is the HTML template for `'app-merchandise-dialog'`:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Info</ng-template>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Name of the item" formControlName="name" 
        cdkFocusInitial>
        <mat-error *ngIf="gearItemForm.get('name').invalid">You must enter a 
       <strong>name</strong></mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
  <...>
 </mat-step>
 <...>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

The two `divs` I am trying to target are in the DOM but are not in the HTML template.

I understand that `':host'` will only target, the single HTML node which represents any given component/element. In this case `':host'` would only target the `'app-merchandise-dialog'` node, if I wanted to for example add a border around it.

I understand that `':host /deep/ .mat-horizontal-content-container'` will target only the host component descendants' that have the class `'mat-horizontal-content-container'`.

However, why am I not able to only use:

```
`
.mat-horizontal-content-container{
 padding: 0;
}
`
```

As this does nothing to the component that has `'mat-horizontal-content-container'` class on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) for Angular components (ViewEncapsulation.Emulated) achieves style scoping by adding an attribute containing a surrogate id to the elements of the component template and pre-processing the style rules provided via styles or styleUrls, adding the new host element attribute to all selectors, so that the styling rules you define for a component only apply to that component and not the contents its child components.  The advantage here is that your styling is less likely to have unpredicted effects on other components--in this case, `mat-horizantal-stepper`.

So, for example:

```
<div class="className">
...
</div>
```

would end up being rendered as something like

```
<div class="className" _ngcontent-0>
...
</div>
```

and your styling rules will compile to target that attribute specifically, like:

```
div.className[_ngcontent-0] {
  ...
}
```

The trick to understanding your example is that `div.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container` and `div.mat-horizontal-content-container` are both inside of `mat-horizantal-stepper`, a child component of `app-merchandise-dialog` with its own encapsulation rules, and therefore will not be given those surrogate ID attributes.  What that `/deep/` selector does is tells the angular compiler to stop targeting that attribute.

So, while `:host .className` will compile to

```
host-element .className[_ngcontent-0] {
   ...
}
```

`:host /deep/ .className` will compile to

```
host-element .className {
   ...
}
```

---

By the way, you can turn off this view encapsulation feature like this:

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

which will allow your styling rules to apply globally instead; of course, then you need to be more careful about unintended application of your styling rules.

Comment: That makes sense, and I was aware of the different ViewEncapsulations, but in the example above, isn’t technically the ‘Form’ element or the ‘mat-horizontal-stepper’ a child element of the main component? But I can target those just fine and you said that styles I define only effect that component and not its children. Those two mentioned components are children of the main component no?

Comment: The code above seems to be from your template file. Please have a look at the actually generated dom. You will find occurrences of `ng-content*` classes and elements, which is how Angular handles the components tree. Hence the need to use deep selectors.

Comment: You can target the `form` and `mat-horizontal-stepper` elements directly, because they are direct children of `app-merchandise-dialog`, and therefore receive those surrogate ID attributes.  That `mat-horizantal-stepper`, however, is its own component with its own encapsulation rules, so its children will not have those surrogate ID attributes.  If you replace `mat-horizantal-stepper` with a non-component element (like a `div`), you'll find that you are able to target its children as expected.

Comment: That makes so much sense now. Can you please update the answer to include this bit of information so its easier to find and ill be sure to mark it as an answer!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  Just updated my answer--please feel free to suggest any revisions that would have made this clearer to you, and I'm happy to make further updates.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nuance to this related to dynamically created components with emulated view encapsulation. This is specifically for [dynamic components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) including [Angular Material Portal](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal). If you're not using dynamic components the following will be confusing.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12215) for this on Github, but it's been open for years without any update.

The primary issue is that it doesn't set the `_ngcontent-app-c100` attribute on the dynamic component so the parent cannot style it without `::ng-deep`. This is pretty bad because it means you can't even set `margin` on a dynamic component without `::ng-deep`!

(Any other issues of not being able to set styles 'inside the child' are not specific to dynamic components).

[I just added an extensive answer that uses a custom directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12215#issuecomment-872533034).